# Apply CSS style on content of input element

Tags: html, css

```
input[type="radio"][class="selectorPrev"]:hover+ label:before {
content:'Previous image';
z-index:999;
position:relative;
}
```

Is it possible to apply margin-left:10px only on the content propertie and leave all the res the same? How to do this?

Comment: why not use `.selectorPrev` for class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to specify the pseudo element to be a `block` or `inline-block` first, as it is generated as an inline element and, therefor, cannot have a margin.

```
input[type="radio"][class="selectorPrev"]:hover + label:before {
  content:'Previous image';
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It moves the whole input element to the left. I only want to move the content sign.

Comment: No it doesn't, at least not with what you've given us. Perhaps you have other styles that are conflicting? Here's a jsfiddle showing you the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/97Q2W/

Comment: Thanks for the sollution. But as I was searching for more info, I found that the content propertie is not advised for displaying info content. I used a different soollution. Many thanks anyway.